# Are there any programs that supports NRPC? (Lotus Notes RPC)

Tags: wget, lotus-notes

Are there any implementations of the Lotus Notes RPC (port 1352)?

Example:

```
wget NRPC://<Server-hint-or-host>/bar/foo.xls -O foo.xls
```

So that we can download a file that is only reachable via a Lotus Notes DB?

Comment: not a direct answer but Notes server would normally allow http(s) access to databases so you could try that. Here is a doc showing how to compose URL paths for various database elements/tasks (files included, look for 'Opening attachments, image files, and OLE objects'): [Domino_URL_cheat_sheet](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/library/ls-Domino_URL_cheat_sheet/)

Comment: assuming Windows/notes client installed you could also use Powershell to access those databases natively, see eg. here:  http://baldwin-ps.blogspot.com/2013/08/lotus-notes-and-powershell-retrieve-acl.html

Comment: It is not really normal for a Domino server to allow http access. It's an optional feature that would only be enabled by an organization that wants to support browser access to Notes.

Comment: @rhsatrhs Yes probably bad wording on my part. I just wanted to be concise; I know it requires http server task and it's entirely admin/config controllable (as is rest of the access to databases), but with IBM pushing for Xpages I'd thought there is good chance web server is started.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find any pre-written programs that do exactly what you want. There several different APIs available for accessing Lotus Notes data via NRPC. There is a C API, a C++ API, a Java API, and a COM API. You can write a program in almost any language to use the latter one, including any scripting language that supports some equivalent of CreateObject. Here's a `link to IBM documentation` on the COM classes.

Note: all of the APIs require that the Lotus Notes client (or Domino server) code must be installed on the machine that is running the API. Also note that the Notes COM classes are officially not supported on 64 bit windows. They can be made to work, with a few problems -- but the ones I know of would not stop you from writing code to get attachments from documents.